# sfml и gcc компиляция

Tags: c++, makefile, sfml, g++

По ролику из YouTube выполнил установку SFML и пытаюсь скомпилировать при помощи g++ прописав в makefile строку с теми же параметрами что и в видео.

Мой makefile :

> all:
> gсс first.cpp -o first.exe -DSFML_STATIC -I E:\tutorials\SFMLWinGccStatic\SFMLWinGCCStatic\sfml1\include -L E:\tutorials\SFMLWinGccStatic\SFMLWinGCCStatic\sfml1\lib -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -lfreetype -ljpeg

Получаю ошибки:

> e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-graphics-s
> e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-window-s
> e:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ljpeg
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
> mingw32-make.EXE: *** [all] Error 1

Что у меня не так?

Comment: Ну а в указанной папке действительно есть указанная библиотека?

Comment: `-lsfml-window` А у вас `-lsfml-window-s`  (И так же со всеми флагами от sfml)

Comment: @user7860670 в каком именно ? у меня 2 пути. они рабочие - проверил, однако по таким путям файлов нет. все ведь делал по инструкции. как он мне так распоковал ((

Comment: @user7860670  таких файлов вообще нету

Comment: @user7860670 вы уверены , что эти параметры должны быть реальные файлы ???

Comment: @Lofectr я пишу как у мужика в видео ролике ))) ок. сейчас уберу -s везде

Comment: *я пишу как у мужика в видео ролике* - а надо понимать, что делать, а для это следует заглянуть в документацию gcc/ У большинства ютуб туториалов уровень ниже плинтуса